# Javascript function for generating similar numbers

Tags: javascript, random

Given a floating point number, help me write a function that generates a number with a modified hundredth of a decimal place.

For example:

```
4.32 => 4.38
5.10 => 5.11
8.37 => 8.31
```

The following are **NOT** following

```
4.32 => 4.29
9.99 => 10.00
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a perfectly legitimate question asking for help writing a function. I'm brain farting.

Comment: Not my downvote, but perhaps adding in your attempt at coding this would help.  Some people like to see some indication that you tried yourself first and aren't just asking for someone to do it for you.

Comment: @Mike Downvotes are often unjustified and never commented sadly.

Comment: Gee, you would think with 3.1k rep, people like that would realize I know the etiquette around here.

Comment: How is the counterexample of `4.32 => 4.29` not ok?  It's still the same integer, right?

Comment: @maerics You're right. I amended by statement. Has to have the same tenth decimal place too. My bad.

Comment: To clarify, your desired results are not "within a hundredth". What I think you mean is that the digits only change in the hundredths place or smaller. When I think of "within a hundredth" of 4.32, that means `4.31 < x < 4.33`.

Comment: @Wiseguy Correct again. I modified the question to clear that up.

Comment: Now, here's another question. If choosing random numbers, you could end up with the same number you input. Is that acceptable, or _must_ the output be different from the input?

Comment: I was going to do that part myself, because I figured it would help clarify the question. In the end, the number shouldn't be the same as the original, but I'd be happy with a solution that is still capable of producing the same number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function simNumber(num) {
    return Math.floor((Math.floor(num * 10) + Math.random()) * 10) / 100;
}
```

Comment: This is good except it can return the same number, which might be ok with you.  See my answer which adds rejection sampling to ensure the number is different.

Comment: posted same comment as maerics - so removed

Answer (score 2):

Updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/RHy5d/1/

```
var num = 3.21;

var newNum = (Math.floor(num*10) + Math.random())/10;

var newNumRounded = Math.floor(newNum*100)/100;
```

Comment: I think you should change `Math.round` for `Math.floor` too, because it would break for `Math.random() >= 0.995`

Answer (score 2):

```
function similar(num) {
    var result = num;
    while (result == num) {
        result = parseFloat(
            num.toFixed(2).substring(0,3) + 
            Math.random().toString().substr(2,1)
        );
    }
    return result;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3dst4/8KLFa/

Comment: I think you meant "result = parseFloat(..." not return.

Comment: @NoelWalters * innocent whistle *

Answer (score 1):

This function replaces the digit in the hundredths place with a random digit [0,9] and then does rejection sampling in case it picked the same number.  Should work ok:

```
function randomHundredths(x) {
  var r, y;
  do {
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // [0, 9]
    y = Number(x.toFixed(2).replace(/\d$/, r));
  } while (y == x);
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function simNumber(num) {
    return parseFloat(num.toString() + Math.random().toString().substr(2,1));
}
```

A demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2QNqw/

Comment: What if the starting number is to 2 decimal places, as in the examples?

Comment: @James Montagne: Add `num.toString().length` .

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
function simNumber(num){
    return Math.floor(num) + Math.random()
}
```

It's worth noting however that the random function won't necessarily return a value to two decimal places.

Clarification: Math.random() return > 0 and < 1

Comment: This could also change the tenths digit. Asker wants the same tenths digit, only changing on the hundredths level.

Comment: According to the w3c website random will return a value between > 0 and < 1.

Comment: @SOliver Correct, but that's not what he wants. If random number is `0.5`, then `9.99 + 0.5 == 10.49`, which is not a valid result. The result should start with `9.9` and have a random hundredths digit.